# Sum Of even numbers among the input of N numbers

Tags: python, sum

How to find the sum of even numbers from entered N numbers?
i tried the below code but cant find the required output.

```
n=int(input('Enter the number:'))
if(n<=0):
    print('Enter a valid number')
else:
    sum=0
    count = 0
    while(n>0):
        for count in range (i % 2 ==0)
            sum+=n
             n-=1            
    print(sum)
```

Comment: inclusive of `n` or no?

Comment: Are you basically after `sum(range(2, n + 1, 2))` ?

Comment: what output did you expect?

Comment: @aws_apprentice inclusive of n

Comment: @JonClements no, i just want the sum on even numbers, like imagine i input n=10 then i want the sum on even numbers between 0-10, pls help

Comment: @RajathcS which that does... did you try it?

Comment: @JonClements yes i did, it aint returning rightful output

Comment: @RajathcS, the answer JonClements provides answers the question

Comment: @RajathcS `sum(range(2, 10 + 1, 2))` gives `30` which seems correct to me...

Answer (score 1):

this was more or less solved in comments by passing a `range` with `step` to `sum`. Most pythonic way:

```
sum(range(2,n+1,2))
```

In that particular case, this can be improved to use a simple math expression to reduce complexity

since the sum of integers from 1 to n is `n*(n+1)//2`, the sum of even numbers is
the double, with n divided by 2 (`n` is *even* here but it also works with odd numbers thanks to integer division) so:

```
n//2 * (n//2+1)
```